# Angular6 Its possible to have a document scanner on web app

Tags: angular6, document, image-scanner

It's possible to have a document scanner in an angular web app, when I'm on a mobile I need to upload or take a picture of a document if you decide to take a picture open the camera and this recognize the edges of the page and do something like camscan.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about `Angular` running on `Ionic framework`, yes you do have access to the camera, please see here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera/

This is an example I build using the camera using Ionic Framework: https://github.com/hamilton-lima/glassCamera

This is where the camera data is retrieved: https://github.com/hamilton-lima/glassCamera/blob/master/src/pages/home/home.ts

Comment: Thanks, but no, I have a web page, and I'm trying when the user open it on mobile, the camera opens but i want to know if exist something that can detect and create like a scanner but not on ionic